# Invoke a ServiceFabric Service via Powershell

Tags: service-fabric-stateless, azure-service-fabric

My team has developed a ServiceFabric application with several services. These services use each-other within the application, but for administration purposes, I want to call directly into one of the services from PowerShell.

From within the services a proxy object is created and used:

```
var myServiceProxy = ServiceProxyFactory.CreateServiceProxy<IMyServiceInterface>("fabric://Application/MyService")
var result = await myServiceProxy.SendSomeData(bytearrayHere);
```

I want to be able to send a file to the same service via PowerShell. Is this possible and how do I do that? This is on my box so I have all the certificates/secrets that may be needed.

Comment: Are you talking about sending the request to service or to particular service instance?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create the `ServiceProxy` by using [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object?view=powershell-6) `New-Object` and directly call `SendSomeData`.

As a workaround, you could create a service that hosts a [web api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-dotnet-app#create-an-aspnet-web-api-service-as-a-reliable-service), and POST a file to it by using the [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Invoke-RestMethod?view=powershell-5.1) `Invoke-RestMethod`.